# Interior of a set J

Tags: probability

I am a little stuck on a question because I am unsure of what int(J) is:
F(x) is a distribution function of P. We have $J=F^{-1}(0,1)=\{x|F(x) \in (0,1)\}$.
I know since F is non decreasing, J is an interval, which is open in the right endpoint (since F is right continuous) and open or closed in the left endpoint.
How would I find int(J)?

Comment: The interior of an interval with endpoints $a<b$ (no matter if closed, open, or half-open) is the open interval $(a,b)$. This includes the cases when $a=-\infty$ or $b=\infty$. In general, the interior of a set $J$ is the largest open set contained in $J$.